# JSoup: how to access a cell without class

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to fetch data from a HTML file into my java code. It all goes well when my cell has a class name. Is it possible to get "next cell" or something like that? Here is a part of HTML and my code.

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Termin</th>
<th>Dzień, godzina</th>
<th>Przedmiot</th>
<th>Typ</th>
<th>Nauczyciel</th>
<th>Sala</th>
</tr>
<tr class="">
<td rowspan="2" class="termin">2015-09-30</td>
<td rowspan="2" class="dzien">Śr 07:50 - 09:30</td>
<td>Język obcy</td>
<td>ćwiczenia</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

```java
public class FetchData {
FetchData() {

    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://planzajec.uek.krakow.pl/index.php?typ=G&id=84721&okres=1").get();
        for (Element table : doc.select("table")) {
            for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {

                Elements termin = row.select("td.termin");
                Elements dzien = row.select("td.dzien");
                Elements przedmiot = row.select("td");

                System.out.println(termin.text() + " " + dzien.text());
                System.out.println(przedmiot.text());

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Is your problem solved? If so, please accept one of the answers and don't forget to up-vote all answers that helped you. If not, please clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select elements specifically without a class you can use this:

```
Elements tds = row.select("td:not([class])");
```

This uses the [pseudo selector `:not()` implemented by JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve them with tags. Use getElementsByTag(yourTag) to retrieve all cells with the specified tag, then loop through them with a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
Elements elmnts= doc.select("table tr"); 

for(Element e:elmnts){
   System.out.println(e.select("td:eq(0)").text());
   System.out.println(e.select("td:eq(1)").text());
   System.out.println(e.select("td:eq(2)").text());
   System.out.println(e.select("td:eq(3)").text());
   System.out.println(e.select("td:eq(4)").text());
   System.out.println(e.select("td:eq(5)").text());
}
```

since you have mentioned 6 column in sample data i have provided for the same